# FCM notification title remains "FCM Message"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use the Firebase Cloud Messaging. I send the notifications from a Node.js server to my apps that are registered to the notification system.

My problem is that on Android 5.1 the notification is "FCM Message" even if I setted the title attribute in the nofitification json. It works fine in Android 6.0. I tried to reboot my device as well.

[image]

And this is the code I use to send the notification:

```
function sendNotificationToUser(userToken, message, onSuccess) {
  request({
    url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type' :' application/json',
      'Authorization': 'key='+API_KEY
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      notification: {
        "title": 'My App Name',
        "body": message,
        "sound": 'default'
      },
      to : userToken
    })
  }, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) { console.error(error); }
    else if (response.statusCode >= 400) { 
      console.error('HTTP Error: '+response.statusCode+' - '+response.statusMessage); 
    }
    else {
      onSuccess();
    }
  });
}
```

As you can see the notification title I send is "My App Name" but on device it shows "FCM Message".

What do I have to do?!

Comment: Is it a notification that was handled by `onMessageReceived` or in the notifications tray?

Comment: this is not server side Issue, problem is Android code onMessageReceived

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that it is a problem related to `onMessageReceived` callback.

[image]

As you can see on the [receive a FCM guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

Answer (score 6):

You need to pass the title and then receive it in `remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle()` , this will catch title and then display in the top or pass complete JSON from web and receive like this

`JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());`

Here is the complete method:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // ...
    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
    // Not getting messages here? See why this may be: https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#fcm-android-background
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
}
```

[Ref link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage)

Answer (score 1):

This is expected. (Tested upto Android 10)

FCM has different behaviours for app status (foreground and background / killed).
You should handle this by the payload you sent from server, according to your use case.

The msg sent from server has to be sent in either "notification" or "data" format, from dashboard or server side api.
Note: From firebase dashobard you can only send "notification" body and not data. In such cases, FCM will directly display the notif without giving a callback to your app.

**Server side**
Below are sample formats :

**Notification** Type Format
Note : Android System will by default display the notification in the notification tray and you don't need to display it.

```
 { 
    "to": "your_token_id",
     "notification" : {
             "title" : "FCM Notification title!",
             "body" : "FCM Notification subtext!",
             "content_available" : true,
             "priority" : "high"
     }
}
```

**Data** Format (For receiving callback in app, in foreground and background)
Note : You have to handle callback and display notif on your own.

```
{ 
    "to": "your_token_id",

    "data" : {
         "title" : "FCM Notification Title ",
         "subtext" : "FCM Notification Sub Title",
         "type" : "999",
         "priority" : "high"
    }
}
```

**Android Client**
To handle the payload received in your Android receiver, checl the official guide [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {

    Log.d(TAG, "From: ${remoteMessage.from}")

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    remoteMessage.data.isNotEmpty().let {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.data)

        if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
            // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use WorkManager.
            scheduleJob()
        } else {
            // Handle message within 10 seconds
            handleNow()
        }
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    remoteMessage.notification?.let {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: ${it.body}")
    }

    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
}
```

Check the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how i get the title from remote messages:

```
 var title = ""
 override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    if (remoteMessage.notification != null) {
        title = remoteMessage.notification!!.title!!
    }
}


val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, channelId)
                         .setContentTitle(title)
```